# wpdb Insert unknown post data dynamic foreach loop

Tags: database, wpdb, array

I have this old function which I would like to use in WordPress.

```
public function database_insert( $table, $data ) {
        $data_key = "(";
        $data_value = "(";
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value)  {
            if ( $key != "speichern" ) {
                if ( $i != 0 ) {
                    $data_key = $data_key.", ";
                    $data_value = $data_value.", ";
                }

                $data_key = $data_key.$key;

                if ( $value == "NULL" ) {
                    $data_value = $data_value.$value;
                } else {
                    $data_value = $data_value."'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->conn, $value)."'";
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }

        $data_key = $data_key.")";
        $data_value = $data_value.")";
        $i = 0;
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." ".$data_key." VALUES ".$data_value;
        $result = mysqli_query( $this->conn, $query ); 
        echo mysqli_error( $this->conn );
        
        if ( $result == 1 ) { 
            return mysqli_insert_id( $this->conn );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out how to do this.Does anyone of you have any idea whether this is possible?

Comment: what are you going to use it for? If you are inserting posts then why not use `wp_insert_post` instead? Raw sql queries won't update caches, fire actions needed for plugins to work, etc, it will cause a lot of problems that are easily avoided

Comment: These are not posts, but data that are stored in a custom database via form submit. In my case, these are just integers. Fire actions for my plugin already exist.

Comment: Then I don't see how this class would be used differently, it would work exactly the same way, be set up the same way, etc you're going to have to be more specific about what it is that's eluding you

Comment: Do I use wpdb->insert or wpdb->prepare?

Comment: `prepare` does not the do the same thing as `insert`, `prepare` does not make DB calls, it's a security function. It would be like asking if you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_query`. I strongly recommend you read the official docs for WPDB and look at the examples. But I don't see why `wpdb` is relevant here? Your class already uses `mysqli`, the conversion to use `WPDB` is unnecessary